# Awk manipulating file into desired output

Tags: awk, struct

I am trying to manipulate this file into a format i wanted by the use of awk. 
this are the input and desired ouput. Please help....

---

Input File

> ```
>                           =================================================================================================================
>                           0                                    Managed=1
>                           =================================================================================================================
>                           ManagedId                     1
>                           application             t[0] = 
>                           faultTolStates              s[2] = Managed=1,Equipment=1
>                           helChRe                    Struct{3}
>                           >>> 1.helCheResCode = 99 (INITIAL_VALUE)
>                           >>> 2.message = 
>                           >>> 3.startTime = 
>                           helCheSched                  t[0] = 
>                           loglName                          QWERT01
>                           mimInfo                              Struct{3}
>                           >>> 1.mimName = QWERT_NO_MODEL
>                           >>> 2.mimVersion = 1.2564
>                           >>> 3.mimRelease = 
>                           productName                          XYZ1234
>                           productNumber                        
>                           productRevision                      
>                           productType                          Node
>                           site                                 QWERT01
>                           userLabel                            QWERT01
>                           =================================================================================================================
>                           1                                    Managed=2
>                           =================================================================================================================
>                           etc.....
>                           etc....
>                           etc....
>                           etc....
> ```

---

Desired Output File

> ```
>                           Managed=1 ManagedId                 1
>                           Managed=1 application               t[0] = 
>                           Managed=1 faultTolStates            s[2] = Managed=1,Equipment=1
>                           Managed=1 helChRe                   Struct{3}
>                           Managed=1 helCheResCode             99 (INITIAL_VALUE)
>                           Managed=1 message 
>                           Managed=1 startTime
>                           Managed=1 helCheSched               t[0] = 
>                           Managed=1 logName                   QWERT01
>                           Managed=1 mimInfo                   Struct{3}
>                           Managed=1 mimName                   QWERT_NO_MODEL
>                           Managed=1 mimVersion                1.2564
>                           Managed=1 mimRelease
>                           Managed=1 productName               XYZ1234
>                           Managed=1 productNumber                        
>                           Managed=1 productRevision                      
>                           Managed=1 productType               Node
>                           Managed=1 site                      QWERT01
>                           Managed=1 userLabel                 QWERT01
>                           Managed=2 ETC .............
>                           Managed=2 ETC.............
>                           Managed=2 ETC.............
>                           Managed=2 ETC.............
>                           Managed=2 ETC.............
>                           Managed=2 ETC.............
> ```

Comment: So by `trying` you mean posting before and after samples and expecting someone to write the script for you?

Answer (score -1):

This might not fully take into account all the details of your data, but for the example input at least it seems to give the desired output. At worst it should be a good starting point for you:

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]/ && $2 ~ /Managed=[0-9]/ { prefix=$2; next } !($1 ~ /^========/) { print prefix, $0 }' managed.txt
Managed=1 ManagedId                     1
Managed=1 application             t[0] = 
Managed=1 faultTolStates              s[2] = Managed=1,Equipment=1
Managed=1 helChRe                    Struct{3}
Managed=1 >>> 1.helCheResCode = 99 (INITIAL_VALUE)
Managed=1 >>> 2.message = 
Managed=1 >>> 3.startTime = 
Managed=1 helCheSched                  t[0] = 
Managed=1 loglName                          QWERT01
Managed=1 mimInfo                              Struct{3}
Managed=1 >>> 1.mimName = QWERT_NO_MODEL
Managed=1 >>> 2.mimVersion = 1.2564
Managed=1 >>> 3.mimRelease = 
Managed=1 productName                          XYZ1234
Managed=1 productNumber                        
Managed=1 productRevision                      
Managed=1 productType                          Node
Managed=1 site                                 QWERT01
Managed=1 userLabel                            QWERT01
Managed=2 etc.....
Managed=2 etc....
Managed=2 etc....
Managed=2 etc....
```